# Maximum weighted pairing algorithm for complete graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, matching, scilab

### The mathematical problem

Let there be *2n* persons, and `C(i,j)` the "cost" of having *i* and *j* work together (the function `C` is quick to compute, in my case it is a given matrix, and is symmetric). The question is to find the arrangement of *2n* pairs of persons that minimizes the sum of the costs of each pair.

This should be done in polynomial complexity in *n*, and implemented relatively easily in the Scilab language (input : cost matrix, output : pairings, for instance a *n*-by-2 matrix of indexes). I am aware that "relatively easily" is subject to interpretation...

### Previous research

This problem is actually solved by the Blossom algorithm. See for instance [this paper](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/papers/BLOSSOM5.html).

However, this (and its variants) looks like a nightmare to implement. My real problem is for *n=20*, so although brute force (= trying all possible pairings) is not OK (brute-forcing *n=8* took an hour on my computer), pretty much anything better than brute force should do the trick; if I can avoid one week of coding at the cost of one hour of computation I'm in.

I was thinking along the lines of using the [Hungarian/Munkres algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) on a *2n*-by-*2n* array filling the diagonal with `+%inf` and other elements by the symmetric cost matrix, then somehow selecting from the resulting permutation a relevant pairing, but I fail to find a reliable way to do this. (Note, the Hungarian algorithm is already coded for a separate section, so you may use it without cost to the "easy to implement" requirement.)

<del>I hope that compared to the blossom-algorithm problem, the completeness of the graph allows for some shortcuts...</del> *(Edit: see DE's comment below, this is wrong for semi-obvious reasons)*

Comment: The completeness of G is sort of irrelevant in general because some edges may have high weights and specifically for the Blossom algorithm because it's a primal-dual algorithm and maintains a general matching on the subgraph of tight edges. The Hungarian algorithm is for bipartite graphs. There won't be a simple fix to get it to do general graphs, because the LP odd cycle constraint is just complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know Scilab I am afraid, but if you are willing to use Python it is very easy as the [Networkx library](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching.html#networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching) provides support for this function:

```
import networkx as nx
import networkx.algorithms.matching as matching

def C(i,j):
    return i*j

n=40
G=nx.Graph()
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        G.add_edge(i,j,weight = -C(i,j))
M = matching.max_weight_matching(G,maxcardinality=True)
for i in M:
    print i,'with',M[i]
```

This code prints out the answer within a second.

The function C defines the cost of pairing i with j.  Note that the weights are set to -C(i,j) in order to transform the max_weight_matching into a min_weight_matching algorithm.

Comment: I can do with Python (which is quite similar). Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Can weights be negative?

Comment: If they are not allowed to be negative, you could add a fixed offset to all weights to make them positive.  I believe the networkx implementation does support negztive weights.